# JAVA alternative to declare TreeMap

Tags: java, jsp, generics, treemap, tomcat5.5

I'm trying to create a TreeMap which is capable of storing multiple beans(Row) mapped to one key. My current declaration of the TreeMap is :

```
Map<String, List<Row>> rowmap = new TreeMap<String, List<Row>>();
```

With this kind of declaration i can easily use this method to add :

```
rowmap.get(combinedKey).add(rowlst);
```

This was working well in my local machine. The problem due to some issue in the Live Tomcat server, I couldn't use the declaration mentioned above to declare the Map, it throws these errors :

```
Syntax error on token "<", ( expected
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression
Syntax error on token "<", ( expected
Syntax error on token "(", invalid Expression
```

So I declared this way :

```
Map rowmap = new TreeMap();
```

this solves the previous error but i couldn't use `rowmap.get(combinedKey).add(rowlst);` to add multiple values to a key because `.add` is defined in List not TreeMap, from my understanding i need declare the TreeMap this way : `Map<String, List<Row>> rowmap = new TreeMap<String, List<Row>>();` to be able to use `rowmap.get(combinedKey).add(rowlst);`.

It would be great if anyone could suggest a workaround to solve this problem. I'm open to all suggestion.Thanks a lot!

EDIT : 
Tomcat version : 5.5.9
Java version : 1.6.0_41-b02

Comment: Why is Live Tomcat Server trying to compile a Java program???  I have a feeling you've misidentified the problem.  I think you need to focus on tracking down and fixing that, instead of doing damage to your Java code.

Comment: @ajb JSP probably?

Comment: And I agree the production environment should not have to compile java code.

Comment: What Java version is your Tomcat server running on? Pre-Java 5?

Comment: As @RobbyCornelissen is hinting, you should upgrade your Tomcat server to run on a newer version of Java. To get that error, you're running on Java 1.4 or earlier. Java 1.4 came out in 2002 and was end-of-lifed in 2008. *It's ancient!*

Comment: pls post the part of your code where you get the error and version of your java and Tomcat too

Comment: Thanks for suggestions guys but I tried to advise the management to upgrade the Java, but i don't enough privilege to do it. So the best way for me is to stick with the current version, Java 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of add method use put for Maps.
put(K key, V value) for example: rowmap.put(combinedKey,rowlst);

Comment: Im planning to map multiple values to a key but Maps. put(K key, V value) will overwrite the the previous value mapped to the key. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Then you could retrieve firstly the values and the add to them your new list and save again to the key for example:
    List  rowvalues = (List ) rowmap.get(key);
    rowvalues.addAll(rowlst);
    rowmap.put(key, rowvalues);